# Importing 'listed shares' from Euronext website (European stock exchange)

Tags: python, finance

I'm trying to import a text file (.txt) of 'listed shares' information with python from the euronext.com website (this is the website of the largest European stock exchange).

I got the url from https://live.euronext.com/en/products/equities/list and checking what page the 'download' button led me to.

```
url_euronext = 'https://live.euronext.com/pd/data/stocks/download?mics=ALXB%2CALXL%2CALXP%2CXPAR%2CXAMS%2CXBRU%2CXLIS%2CXMLI%2CMLXB%2CENXB%2CENXL%2CTNLA%2CTNLB%2CXLDN%2CXESM%2CXMSM%2CXATL%2CVPXB&display_datapoints=dp_stocks&display_filters=df_stocks'

listed_shares = requests.get(url_euronext).text.split('\n')
```

I was expecting for python to import the same text file. However, the above code gives me an empty string as output.

```
listed_shares
Out[3]: ['']
```

How do I go about this?